# JSON error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

I'm trying to find answer for this error

```
$(function(){
   var fileJSON = "http://onlinepayment.majorcineplex.com/api/1.0/showtime?movie_id=163&cinema_id=53&date=2012-07-02&callback=?";

   $.getJSON(fileJSON,function(data){
       alert("check");
   });  
});
```

it's not alert"check" and have error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : "

Comment: Try taking out "callback=?" in the URL?

Comment: have other error 

"XMLHttpRequest cannot load "

Comment: That API does not support JSONP. There is no callback function added, it's just plain JSON, so you only think it supports JSONP, but it really doesn't.